# c++ thread not spawning causing mutex not unlocking

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a `c++`-program which executes threads to process certain items. To sync these threads, I assign Pool numbers in order to prevent (too many) concurrent threads. However, it occurs that some threads are never actually 'received' by the function the thread is calling. To handle the thread spawning, I use the following `while` loop in `main`:

```
while (true) {
    for (auto& Group: Groups) {
        unsigned long long ProcessingPoolNr = GetProcessingPoolNr();

        cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Received poolnr: " << ProcessingPoolNr << " fo group: " << FileGroup.Name << endl;

        try {
            thread GroupHandler(HandleGroup, ProcessingPoolNr, Group);
            GroupHandler.detach();
            }
        catch (const std::exception &ex) {
            cout << "Thread exited with exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
            }

        cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Detached group: " << FileGroup.Name << endl;

        }
    SleepForSeconds(1);
    }
```

This executes a thread and waits for a new `PoolNr`. (Currently, only 1 PoolNr is available, so only 1 concurrent thread is running). The `GetProcessingPoolNr`-functions:

```
unsigned long long GetGroupProcessingPoolNr() {
    bool FoundPool = false;
    unsigned long long PoolNr = 0;
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Getting poolnr" << endl;

    bool Sleep = false;

    while (!FoundPool) {
        if (Sleep) {
            SleepForMilliSeconds(1);
            }
        GroupProcessingPoolMutex.lock();
        try {
            for (auto& Pool : GroupProcessingPool) {
                if (Pool.second) {
                    //THIS POOL IS ALREADY PROCESSING
                    }
                else {
                    FoundPool = true;
                    PoolNr = Pool.first;
                    GroupProcessingPool[Pool.first] = true;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (const exception& e) {
            string Message =__FUNCTION__;
            Message += " error: ";
            Message += e.what();
            Exit(Message);
            }
        GroupProcessingPoolMutex.unlock();
        Sleep = true;
        }
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Got poolnr: " << PoolNr << endl;
    return PoolNr;
    }
```

So far so good, however as you can see, the `GroupProcessingPool` is locked by a mutex. To release a `PoolNr`, the running thread will release it at the end. The spawned thread has the following code:

```
void HandleGroup(unsigned long long PoolNr, Group Group) {
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Handling group: " << Group.Name << endl;
    //DO SOME PROCESSING HERE
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Handled group: " << Group.Name << endl;
    ReleaseGroupProcessingPool(PoolNr);
    }
```

The `ReleaseGroupProcessingPool`-function is:

```
void ReleaseGroupProcessingPool(unsigned long long PoolNr) {
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Releasing poolnr: " << PoolNr << endl;
    GroupProcessingPoolMutex.lock();
    GroupProcessingPool[PoolNr] = false;
    GroupProcessingPoolMutex.unlock();
    cout << GetLogDateTime() << "|" << GetLogType("Info") << "|Released poolnr: " << PoolNr << endl;
    }
```

As you can see, the expected flow is something like:

```
Getting PoolNr
Got PoolNr: 1
Received PoolNr: 1 for group: x
Detached group: x
Handling group: x
Handled group: x
Releasing PoolNr: 1
Released PoolNr: 1
```

---- THIS REPEATS ---

So, the problem that occurs is that I am missing the `logging` from the called `function` in the `thread`. It seems that the `thread` is spawned and `detached`, but that the `function` is never ran. So, the `mutex` will never be released, because releasing occurs from within the `function` / `thread`. What can cause this problem?

Comment: *"releasing occurs from within the function / thread."* - you're describing locking in one function, while unlocking in another, and the posted code doesn't do that. `HandlerGroup` neither locks, nor unlocks any mutexes. `ReleaseGroupProcessingPool` both locks and unlocks the same mutex (and frankly, is begging for a scope-based lock like `std::lock_guard`), and `GetGroupProcessingPoolNr` locks, enumerates, then unlocks the mutex. So, I have no idea what you're talking about,  "releasing occurs from within the function/thread". So does locking (both within ReleaseGroupProcessingPool) .

Comment: Added to that, why this isn't managed with a work queue with a dedicated (possibly dynamic) thread pool is a thing to consider. Rarely, if ever, is a dispatch system that dispatch system that spawns threads, detaches them, then hopes for the best, ever a concrete scalable solution.

Comment: Why do you have a try/catch block?  I don't see anything in that block that is expected to throw a failure.  You'll wind up swallowing a runtime error by having that around.

Comment: @WhozCraig, the function `HandleGroup` calls the function `ReleaseGroupProcessingPool` which unlocks the pool. I use these mutexes because the function to retrieve a poolNr is called from another thread than the unlock, so that's why I use the mutexes. Could you elaborate on how to do this with a thread pool (dynamically?) as you described?

Comment: @selbie, I have added the `try-catch` block because I read an article saying the thread spawn might throw an error. Seemed strange to mee, but I gave it a try (no catch occurs, as expected)

Comment: I meant the try/catch block inside the GetGroupProcessingPoolNr function

Comment: @WhozCraig One function takes the lock, sets the flag and releases the lock. The other function takes the lock, unsets the flag and releases the lock. The flag is what is released in another function.

Comment: So when you say "lock" you don't mean locking a mutex, you mean flagging your predicate state that's protected by your mutex. Ok. I understand now. When/if I get a chance I'll throw together a simple work queue with a dedicated thread pool if you don't have one already. I strongly prefer it to starting up + detaching threads.

Comment: @WhozCraig, alright great thanks